# Verificar existencia de um elemento com Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou automatizando um site e em determinada parte ele apresenta um listbox que quando uma de suas opções é selecionada se tiver valores disponiveis apresenta uma tabela com esses valores. O que eu quero é fazer o sistema verificar se essa tabela existe pra cada uma das opções e se existir pegar seus valores, mas quando eu tento dar um FindElement, se a tabela não existir em determinada opção ao invés dele simplesmente seguir ele joga o erro de n ter achado para o catch. Como faço para dar o FindElement só depois que eu souber que essa tabela está presente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginando que o ID da sua tabela seja `idDaSuaTabela`, você precisa [esperar pela tabela](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element) aparecer até prosseguir:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("idDaSuaTabela")));
```

O atributo `timeoutInSeconds` define o tempo máximo, em segundos, que deseja esperar pelo elemento.

Comment: Vlw a ajuda mas ja consegui, eu criei in try catch e finally so pra verificar isso, ai qnd ele n achava ele jogava no catch, finally e seguia o sistema